# 1960/70's British novel about an attack using sterility as a weapon

Tags: story-identification, novel

Plot revolves around young women who find that when they mature they will only give birth to girls.

Comment: Hi there. While there are unique elements, it's still a bit terse - could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Any other recollection of the plot, the characters, the cover?

Answer (score 14):

Possibly *Implosion* (1967) by Dennis Feltham Jones.

The release year matches, D. F. Jones was British, and sterility is used as a weapon. However, the remaining fertile women find themselves only to bear *boys*, not girls. (still warrants the end of humanity, though)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implosion_(novel)):

> Implosion is a science fiction novel by British writer D. F. Jones, published in 1967, set in a United Kingdom just attacked by an unnamed minor Eastern Bloc country. **The weapon used, 'Prolix', is a chemical sterilant, that, once ingested, renders most women sterile.**
>
> The protagonists are the Minister for Health, Dr. John Bart, M.D., and his wife Julia; he soon finds his Ministry is the most important government entity in the new, post-attack Britain, while his wife is one of the country's few remaining fertile women. In the end, as the Minister for Health, Dr. Bart finds himself creating a new society where fertile women are herded to concentration camps, to spend the rest of their lives reproducing.
>
> Meanwhile, the rest of the world are shooting Prolix at each other, gradually reducing their populations to Britain's circumstance. **At story's end, mankind learns that the genetic quirk that kept some women fertile allows them to only bear boys, thus dooming humanity to extinction.**

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] infertile`, *Implosion* was suggested (but denied) as an answer to [Book about infertility](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/182548/).

Comment: If this is the right answer, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I thank you for the answer to my question. It was "Implosion".   I would like to vote on the answer; but cannot see any voting buttons anywhere. They are probably right under my nose. I am using a PC to access the site.

Comment: @williamwarren you're welcome, enjoy the re-read! :) the "voting buttons" should look like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYXQ2.png); from your point of view, there _should_ be a checkmark under those. :)